# What is the grouping word for "Intra/Inter' feature

Tags: single-word-requests

For Big/Small there is "Size". 
For Long/Short there is "Length".

Whats the grouping word for Intra/Inter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Intra* means "inside" and *inter* means "between" (and *extra* is "outside") so I suppose **location** might as good as anything.

However, *big, small, long* and *short* are all adjectives. *Long* and *short* describe length; *big* and *small* describe size. *Intra* and *inter* are not adjectives — you can't use those words in the same way as the others — and so trying to group them is not really the same thing.

However, *inter-planetary* dust, or travel, is between the planets; *extra-mural* activity covers lessons outside the walls of the school; *intranet* is a network within a company. **location** may well work.

Comment: Pipped to *location* but this answer does add something to the slightly earlier one.

Comment: On the bright side, you just taught this American a new meaning of the word *pip*.

Answer (score 0):

These are known as [locational prefixes](http://www.cram.com/flashcards/locational-prefixes-593423), so you can describe them as *locational*. If you need a noun to use as your "grouping word," you could use *locational prefixes* or simply *location*.